# Is there a Hamcrest matcher to check that a Collection is neither empty nor null?

Tags: java, junit, matcher, hamcrest

Is there a Hamcrest matcher which checks that the argument is neither an empty Collection nor null?

I guess I could always use

```
both(notNullValue()).and(not(hasSize(0))
```

but I was wondering whether there is a simpler way and I missed it.

Comment: That looks pretty simple to me. Also, it's important that your tests express their intent with as much clarity as possible, and that code is very readable.

Comment: I don't really know hamcrest, but logically you could check for `size >= 0`, if the API supports such calls.

Comment: this question's title asks the opposite of this question's body. To answer the  question's title: `assertThat(   metadata, either(  is( empty() )  ).or(  is( nullValue() )  )   );`

Comment: Not an exact match to your question, but you can `assertTrue(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(collectioin))`.  `CollectionUtils` is an Apache Commons Lang class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can combine the [`IsCollectionWithSize`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsCollectionWithSize.html) and the [`OrderingComparison`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.html) matcher:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Collection<String> collection = ...;
    assertThat(collection, hasSize(greaterThan(0)));
}
```

- For `collection = null` you get

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: a collection with size a value greater than <0>
      but: was null
  ```
- For `collection = Collections.emptyList()` you get

  ```
  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expected: a collection with size a value greater than <0>
      but: collection size <0> was equal to <0>
  ```
- For `collection = Collections.singletonList("Hello world")` the test passes.

---

**Edit:**

Just noticed that the following approch is **not** working:

```
assertThat(collection, is(not(empty())));
```

The more i think about it the more i would recommend a slightly altered version of the statement written by the OP if you want to test explicitly for null.

```
assertThat(collection, both(not(empty())).and(notNullValue()));
```

Comment: I accepted your answer because I think that both ways shown here, `hasSize(greaterThan(0))` and `both(not(empty())).and(notNullValue())` are a good way.

Comment: Any reason why I get `1 expectation failed.
JSON path images doesn't match.
Expected: (an empty collection or null)
  Actual: null` when i try to check for empty collection or null with your code : 
`myResponse.body(myArrayAttr, either(empty()).or(nullValue()));`

Answer (score 2):

As I posted in the comments, the logical equivalent of `collection != null` and `size != 0` is
`size > 0`, that implies the collection is not null. A simpler way to express `size > 0` is `there is an (arbitrary) element X in collection`. Below a working code example.

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.hasItem;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.anything;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result = hasItem(anything()).matches(null);
        System.out.println(result); // false for null

        result = hasItem(anything()).matches(Arrays.asList());
        System.out.println(result); // false for empty

        result = hasItem(anything()).matches(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        System.out.println(result); // true for (non-null and) non-empty 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to use Matchers:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anyOf;

assertThat(collection, anyOf(nullValue(), empty()));
```